# Roku app crashing on devices with 1 GB RAM

Tags: memory, crash, roku, brightscript

I'm facing an issue with my Roku app. My app is crashing on all the devices with 1 GB RAM but it is working fine on devices with 1.5 RAM. The crash log is below:

**Execution timeout (runtime error &h23**)

Can anyone help me with this issue? How can I debug the actual root cause ?

Tried Profiler but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

To discourage heavy CPU usage on the render thread, the BrightScript runtime imposes timeouts. The proper way to handle these types of long-running CPU-heavy operations is to move the logic to a [Task](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/task.md) thread. Doing that will allow you to avoid the `Execution Timeout` errors as the execution timeout is not enforced in task threads.

The reason you're seeing it on "devices with 1 GB RAM" is not the ram amount, but rather that those devices typically have slower CPUs, so you get less work done in the same global timeout length.

Comment: Thanks, @TwitchBron for the response. However, I've moved my suspicious logic to Task, it is still crashing. I'll try to see and find out if there's any other heavy work is being done render thread.

Answer (score 1):

In order to identify the possible root cause you could telnet to port `8080`:

```
telnet roku-ip-address 8080
```

and check for possible memory leaking. I would suggest using at least next commands:

`sgnodes roots` - to check for orphan nodes. You would want to get rid of them because such nodes are no longer used by the app but still consume some memory.

`loaded_textures` - displays the current set of images loaded into texture memory

`free` - provides a snapshot of the amount of in-use and free memory on the device.

To review all possible commands please visit https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/debugging/debugging-channels.md#scenegraph-debug-server-port-8080-commands

Also, when the app crashes check in the debug console on port `8085` for the current executed suspended threads (type `threads` in the console) and review if there are `Tasks` that are not being used. Having unnecessary threads running would also impact memory consumption and could cause `Execution timeouts` at some point.